# A statement related to Hilbert Nullstelensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

By Hilbert Nullstelensatz we know that for any field $k$, every maximal ideal of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ has residue field a finite extension of $k$. I also did an exercise which goes: any integral domain $A$ which is a finite $k$- algebra is a field.

Then there is a remark after this exercise that says: it follows by Hilbert Nullstelensatz and this exercise that prime ideals of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ with finite residue ring are the same as maximal ideals of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$.

Could someone please explain me how this works?

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a prime ideal then the residue ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is an integral domain and naturally a $k$-algebra (quotients of $k$-algebras by ideals are also $k$-algebraS). So if we assume the residue ring is finitely generated, then we have the hypotheses of the second so the residue ring is a field. It is then a classical result of algebra that in a ring $R$, $P$ an ideal is maximal iff $R/P$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is Hilbert Nullstelensatz used in this answer? or is it not necessary here?

Comment: @BenV the Nullstellensatz gives the converse: $m$ maximal implies $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/m$ is a finite extension of $k$ by the Nullstellensatz. As a finite finite field extension of $k$, the residue field $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/m$ is in particular a finite $k$-algebra.

Comment: @MorganO Do we need Hilbert Nullstellnsatz to conclude $k[x_1, ..., x_n]/m$ is a finite $k$-algebra? I thought it would just follow by the fact that it is a quotient of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$.

Comment: @BenV, it's true that any quotient of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a "*finitely generated* $k$-algebra". But when I say the ring is a "*finite* $k$-algebra", I mean that it is finitely generated as a $k$-module (equivalently, a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space). This is a much stronger statement. (I apologize for any confusion due to my terminology. It's a bit nonstandard-- but it's used, for instance, in Miles Reid's [Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry](http://www.amazon.com/Undergraduate-Algebraic-Geometry-Mathematical-Society/dp/0521356628) ).

Comment: No problem! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It makes perfect sense now. I really appreciate it!